# How to scroll through octaves in a piano app using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am trying to make a piano app that can scroll horizontally through octaves. Below is an example from another piano app of what I am trying to do. The arrows scroll through the piano by one octave. I've learned about scrollview, however, it seems like it only allows scrolling is through swiping and not by buttons.

Is this a type of scrollview or is this something different altogether? If anyone can point me in the right direction of what mechanism these buttons use to change the view, I would really appreciate it. [image]

Comment: voting for closure as this is a broad opinion based question with no definite answer. It is likely using a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView where each cell is one octave of the piano. There are many different ways to achieve this, however, hence the downvote.

Comment: I know it's a broad question that's why I asked for someone to point me in the right direction generally of what mechanism is shifting the view of the keyboard. The keys are buttons, do you have a recommendation other than the cell idea?

Comment: Broad questions do not belong on stack overflow. Fortunately, there are plenty of other resources online where this type of question would be appropriate. Just don't want you to be wasting your time here waiting for good answers to a question asking for opinions.

Comment: Fair enough. Truthfully, I am new to programming and I wouldn't mind to have some more experienced programmers give me opinions on how to approach this. What other online resources would you recommend for a question like this?

Comment: try raywenderlich.com - they have a forum

Comment: @BJHStudios This question is indeed very broad (though I'm not sure it's broad enough to be put on hold). It's not particularly opinion-based, though; I'm not sure where you're getting that.

Comment: @EdCottrell can you deliver an answer to the main question here ("Is this a type of scrollview or is this something different altogether?") that isn't opinion based? I feel like only the developer can do that - all we can do is offer our opinions on how it might best be accomplished.

Comment: @BJHStudios That doesn't ask for an opinion. It might be asking for a *guess*, which is also not great, though I'm not sure (I'm not an iOS expert; maybe it's obvious to someone who is). But a guess is not the same as an opinion. I think it's pretty clear that the main question is not "how did this app do this" so much as "how can I do something like what this app does?" As I said, that's very broad, but it's not asking for an opinion.

Comment: @EdCottrell seems like splitting hairs, but that's just my...opinion. I'll still sleep tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you use will probably either be a UIScrollView or will inherit from it, so you can use `setContentOffset(_:animated:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset